# How to create some group of user without password in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-permissions

I am developing multivender ecommerce site in django. In which, i dont want to authenticate some group of user i.e. customer with password but want to authenticate venders with password. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is :-

```
Don't use @login_required on views, in category of users that you don't want to 
authenticate.
```

Comment: If user is not login then i cant get user orders.

Comment: Make a Model of Vender with its view, AND make a different Model of Customer with its view. Add Venders view @login_required and don't add login_required in the view of Customer. So if venders will open they would be require login but Customer would not be compulsory to login.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I meant to say, if customer is not logged in then how can i track his orders.

Comment: Can i see your Code ? Publish your Code Please

Comment: I have'nt written code yet, just asking that "is there any logic to do that?